# Javascript function invocation using DOM Events

Tags: javascript, html

How come the `displayDate()` function "`document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;`" in [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it" to execute the displayDate() function.</p>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;

function displayDate() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

is being invoked without the `()`. Notice that when you introduce the `()`, like so; `document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate();`, the function will execute automaotically without the pressing of the `Try it` button; `<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>`. It is a code snippet from w3schools.com: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events2. I'm struggling to get the logic.

Comment: *"is being invoked without the ()"* It's not. You are "giving" the browser a *reference* to the function (hence no `()`) and the browser will invoke the function when the event happens.

Comment: `functionCall()` will always execute directly in javascript. If anything it's the `<div onclick="fc()">...</div>`that is acting like magic because it creates an event listener and wraps your code in an event handler function behind the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly,

```
// CASE 1
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;
```

is equivalent to

```
// CASE 2
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
  displayDate();
};
```

Here, you assign a function to onclick which will be executed on click.

In CASE 1, `displayDate` holds the function, which is assigned to onclick. so it is executed when you click

but when you do

```
// notice () after displayDate
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate();
```

Here, displayDate is executed first & the returned value is assigned to onclick. that is the reason why you see date even before you click on "try it"

Answer (score 0):

In this case assignement is done

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;
```

But in this case the function is called

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bit difficult to wrap your head around as a beginner. If you're familiar with references from other languages such as [c](/questions/tagged/c), you're essentially passing a pointer to the function to the `onClick` handler.

> According to the [MDN Definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick):
>
> `functionRef` is a function name or a function expression. The function receives a `MouseEvent` object as its sole argument. Within the function, this will be the element upon which the event was triggered.

To put it in understandable terms, what happens is you pass a function reference that the `onclick` EventHandler triggers on event and attempts to pass the `event` to whatever is inside the `onclick` DOM onevent handler *(in this case, we should pass event as argument to function reference)*

If we were to pseudo-declare the `onclick` handler, it would look something like this:

```
// this is very simplified, but serves as illustration 
const onclick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLELement>) => {
   yourFunctionReference(event)
}
```

So what happens is every time an event is triggered, the [DOM onevent handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) passes the event to the function reference and invokes the function.

If you invoked the function in the `onclick` handler instead, it would simply pass the returned value to it, which is usually not what you want, eg.

```js
const returnHi = () => 'hi'
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = returnHi();
```

would basically result in

```js
const onclick = (event) => {
  'hi'
}
```

This behaviour is however useful, when you want to pass other arguments to the event handler, consider the following example.

```html
<button name="myBtn" id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const eventCallbackLog = (event, message) => {
 const { name } = event.target
 console.log(`${name} ${message}`)
}

document.getElementById("myBtn")
 .onclick = event => eventCallbackLog(event, 'says hi');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning function reference here ,below line

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate; // function reference
```

Below line will assign the return value of function to the `onclick` which won't make sense unless you return a `function` from the `displayDate()`

```
 document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate(); // Assignins return value
```

Now when you return a function ,it will work

```js
function displayDate() {
  return function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
  }
}

document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate();
```

```html
<p>Click "Try it" to execute the displayDate() function.</p>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;
```

In the above line, you are subscribing the click event of "myBtn" to the **displayDate**
function by assigning the function name to the property **onclick**

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate();
```

In this case, you are invoking the **displayDate** function and the returned value of the **displayDate** function is assigned to the **onlclick** property.

Here **displayDate** function is not returning anything. So **undefined** is assigned to the **onclick** property.

When javascript runtime executes this line, **displayDate** function is executed when evaluating the assignment operation and as **undefined** is assigned to **onclick** nothing will happen when the button is clicked further.

Answer (score 0):

It is the concept of `callback`:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;
```

Assign the named function `displayDate` to the `onClick` callback. It means that as some point the code will call `onclick`, so executing your function.
It works in a similar way to this:

```js
function test(){alert("i'm executed!")}

function executeThis(func){
  setTimeout(function(){
    func() //  <-- here the function is called! 
  }, 2000);
}

executeThis(test); // <-- here the function is passed for reference
```

On the other hand, passing the callback in this way:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate();
```

will pass to the callback the **result** of `displayDate`

for example:

```js
    function test(){
      console.log("i'm executed!"); 
      return function(){
        alert("i'm the return value");
      }
    }

    function executeThis(func){
      setTimeout(function(){
        func() //  <-- here the function RESULT is called! 
      }, 2000);
    }

    executeThis(test()); // <-- here the function is executed and its result is passed
```